# Variable definition in Automake

Tags: makefile, autoconf, automake

I am writing a `Makefile.am` for my autotool package. However I got some problems in generating the dependency files.

```
bin_PROGRAMS=main
main_SOURCES=src/main.cpp
```

With the above format the `automake` can generate the dependency files in a hidden folder `src/.deps`. However, if I replace `src` with a variable `SRCDIR` then the dependency files are put into a folder name "`$SRCDIR/.deps`".

```
SRCDIR=src
bin_PROGRAM=main
main_SOURCES=$(SRCDIR)/main.cpp
```

What's wrong with the second style? I simply replace the src to with a variable but it looks like this variable is not correctly substituted.

Comment: I think that looks right. Are you sure you did exactly that? What does the corresponding line in `Makefile.in` look like? What about in the final `Makefile`? What does `DEPDIR` contain in the final `Makefile`?

Comment: In autotools 'srcdir' is a special variable.  It should be set in you configure.ac with the AC_CONFIG_SRCDIR macro.   I'm not sure what you're trying to do but I think it's conflicting.  Try MYSRCDIR.